# How many days get >1mm of rain in Guimarães and Coimbra?

Tags: weather-and-climate, portugal, coimbra

I'm trying to determine where in Portugal and Spain we might want to stay. On Wikipedia I was able to find the expected **number of days per annum with over 1mm of precipitation** for nearly all the cities in question, except Guimarães and Coimbra, Portugal.

What are their figures?

Answer (score 3):

A very quick google for "[city] Portugal weather monthly" turned up these two links:

[Guimarães climate](https://en.climate-data.org/europe/portugal/guimaraes/guimaraes-57351/) and [Coimbra climate](https://en.climate-data.org/europe/portugal/coimbra/coimbra-160/), both of which have the monthly rainfall in mm per month.

Doing a google for "Coimbra, Portugal days of rain over 1mm" leads to [Rainfall/ Precipitation in Coimbra, Portugal](http://www.coimbra.climatemps.com/precipitation.php) which says it has

> On average there are 138 days per year with more than 0.1 mm rainfall

I can't find the equivalent for Guimarães, but every average monthly rainfall chart shows that the minimum amount of rain is in July and is typically around 12mm.  This is roughly the same as Coimbra, so I'd expect a similar number of days of rain per year.  But it seems that on average Guimarães  gets less rain than Coimbra.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the ratio of 1mm days and 0.1mm days is....

Comment: Unless you melt from getting wet, a 1 mm rain day feels dry.